# How to fetch a set of pages as a Stream?

Tags: scala

How can i consume a service that returns pages as a Stream of items?

Amazon S3, for example, lets you fetch the initial object listing or the next object listing from the previous one.

For example consider this code that simulates such behavior:

```scala
import math._

case class Page(number: Int)

case class Pages(pages: Seq[Page], truncated: Boolean)

class PagesService(pageSize: Int, pagesServed: Int) {
  def getPages =
    Pages((1 to pageSize).map(Page), pageSize < pagesServed)

  def nextPages(previous: Pages) = {
    val first = previous.pages.last.number + 1
    val last = min(first + pageSize, pagesServed)
    Pages((first to last).map(Page), last < pagesServed)
  }
}

object PagesClient extends App {
  val service = new PagesService(10, 100)

  val first = service.getPages
  assert(first.truncated)
  first.pages.foreach(println(_))

  val second = service.nextPages(first)
  second.pages.foreach(println(_))

  val book: Stream[Page] = ???
}
```

How could i write that last expression?

Comment: Do you mean `Stream[Page]` or `Stream[Pages]`?

Comment: Just curious but why not just use `.map(Page)` instead of `.map(toPage)` and get rid of the `def toPage` altogether? Case classes don't require `new`.

Comment: @Jatin I mean Stream[Page] really. In S3 that would be Stream[S3ObjectSummary] (not Stream[ObjectListing])

Comment: @ErikAllik that is just becaust i did not know better, will update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val book: Stream[Pages] = first #:: book.map(service.nextPages).takeWhile(_.pages.nonEmpty)
val pages: Stream[Page] = book.flatten(_.pages)
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if it is a typo. If you mean `Stream[Pages]` it is simple:

```
val book: Stream[Pages] = first #:: book.map(x => service.nextPages(x))
```

If you meant `Stream[Page]` i.e. a stream of `Page` from all pages, then:

```
val first = service.getPages
val second = service.nextPages(first)

val books: Stream[Page] = {
  val currentPages = book.iterator
  val firstPages = currentPages.next.pages.iterator

  def inner(current: Iterator[Page]): Stream[Page] = {
    if (current.hasNext) {
      current.next #:: inner(current)
    } else {
      val i = currentPages.next
      inner(i.pages.iterator)
    }
  }
  inner(firstPages);
}
```

The above basically takes a `Pages`, returns its `Page` as part of stream. If the `Pages` is exhausted, then goes over to the next `Pages` and so on.

Comment: @Eastsun yup corrected it. I added the second element explicitely before, removed it.